# get 3rd div by its class name

Tags: html, css

let say I have the following `HTML`

```
<div class="owl-item"></div>
<div class="owl-item"></div>
<div class="owl-item active"></div>
<div class="owl-item active"></div>
<div class="owl-item active"></div>
<div class="owl-item"></div>
```

I want to select the 3rd div with class name of `active`. I tried the following:

```
.owl-item.active:nth-child(3)
```

but that doesn't work. in jQuery this can be done using `$('.owl-item.active').eq(0)` but it's pure `CSS`

Comment: it's been a while to hear from you. did you checked the answer?

Comment: it works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/2q4y2h9y/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of these

Using jQuery

```
jQuery(".owl-item.active:eq(2)")
```

Using javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll(".owl-item.active")[2]
```

And whatever the code you are using is useful for css

```
.owl-item.active:nth-child(3)
```

Comment: oh, I didn't know `:eq()` itself is css pseudo selector @.@

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have children's so,

```
.owl-item.active:nth-child(3)
```

it won't work. Instead use

```
.owl-item.active:nth-of-type(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This wont work as the element is not the third child of its parent.  You should try `$('. elem:eq(2)')`

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 types of elements with class containing '`.owl-item`'.
There are 3 types of elements with class containing '`.owl-item.active`'.

You should try using '[nth-of-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)' as none of the elements are child elements.

Refer: [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It is not working as the Initial div  is closing just after itself.

Place it at the end and it will work.

Please find below the modified code.

```
<style>
.owl-item.active:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="owl-item">1</div>
    <div class="owl-item">2</div>
    <div class="owl-item active">3</div>
    <div class="owl-item active">4</div>
    <div class="owl-item active">5</div>
    <div class="owl-item">6</div>
</div>
```